# How can I split my dictionary data in python to use pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I stored my dataset with

```
obj = {"features": features, "labels": labels}
```

but because of processing, the shape of each file is different.
for example,

```
np.array(test_b['features']).shape, np.array(test_b['labels']).shape
```

of files are like
`((8, 6, 6, 6, 4), (8, 1))`,
`((31, 6, 6, 6, 4), (31, 1))`,
`((3, 6, 6, 6, 4), (3, 1))`

it would be ok to spill data with 8,31,3 of each dataset so I tried code belows.

```
import torch.utils.data as data

class fruitDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, f_path_list) -> None:
        """
        f_path_list : pickle path list
        """
        self.f_path_list = f_path_list
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.f_path_list)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data_path = self.f_path_list[index]
        data_origin = joblib.load(data_path)
        for i in range(len(data_origin['labels'])):
            X = data_origin['features'][i]
            y = data_origin['labels'][i]
        return X, y
```

and

```
import torch
batch_size = 2

train_dataset= fruitDataset(train_path_list)
test_dataset = fruitDataset(test_path_list)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

I think I've got wrong but I cannot find where is wrong.
How can I split my data correctly and prepare to train properly?

Thanks in advance.